# AutoLoader - data missed by readStream during files are written to Azure Data Lake Storage

Tags: pyspark, azure-blob-storage, databricks, delta-lake, databricks-autoloader

I'm using Databricks AutoLoader to ingest data from files (parquets) to Delta Tables.

https://docs.databricks.com/en/ingestion/auto-loader/index.html

In fact our source system writes files to Azaure Data Lake Storege independent of ETL pipeline. So we might have scenario that we start readStrem and try to read parquets that are stil being written to ADLS.

My question is: how AutoLoader behave against file that is during write operations? Is it any risk to lose data in scenario described above? E.g. readStream will read files only parially or skip files and it won't be read in next run.

Here is more details about our set up.

AutoLoader with directory listing mode and trigger one properties

```
        cloudFile = {
                 "cloudFiles.usenotifications": False
                , "cloudFiles.format": self.source_format
                , "cloudFiles.schemaLocation": self.al_output_path_schema
                , "cloudFiles.maxBytesPerTrigger": '1g'
                , "cloudFiles.inferColumnTypes": True
                , "cloudFiles.validateOptions": False
            }

---------

        df = spark.readStream\
          .format("cloudFiles")\
          .options(**cloudFile)\
          .option("readerCaseSensitive", "false")\
          .option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace", "true")\
          .option("ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace", "true")\
          .option("recursiveFileLookup", "true")\
          .load(input_path)

----------

        df.writeStream\
            .foreachBatch(lambda df, epoch_id: self._al_write_data(df))\
            .option( "checkpointLocation", self.al_output_path_checkpoint )\
            .option( "mergeSchema", "true")\
            .queryName(f'_al_stream_{self.target_schema}_{self.target_name}')\
            .trigger(once=True)\
            .start()
```

How about Trigger.AvailableNow option for AutoLoader? Does it solve my problem?

https://docs.databricks.com/en/ingestion/auto-loader/production.html

I asked DBR consultant about this case and recived the answer that it might happend on Azure Data Lake Storage because the files don't appear atomically. Soon I will do the test but it can be false positive so I have to be sure based on documentations or experience of anyone that using AutoLoader on production environment.

Comment: It may depend on how files are uploaded

Comment: @AlexOtt what do you mean? Could you give more details about how upload methods (which one?) affects on risk of missing data by AutoLoader?

Comment: tool may just create file and then start to append chunks to it. So file will be empty initially. Or it could create a temporary file and then rename it - that's atomic operation

Comment: files are write to ADLS by library Azure.Storage.BLOBS, method "UploadAsync" - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobclient?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: @AlexOtt I done tests and it looks like AutoLoader don't  miss data from file that is being written on ADLS. As I mentioned before the writer use library Azure.Storage.BLOBS, method "UploadAsync" and file on ADLS is appear atomically.

I wander to be 100% sure if should I use "cloudFiles.allowOverwrites" option. More info about this is here: https://docs.databricks.com/en/ingestion/auto-loader/options.html,

Comment: I also find the case similar to my and it was resolved by "cloudFiles.allowOverwrites"
https://vishwajeet-pol.medium.com/databricks-autoloader-with-spark-structured-streaming-using-delta-51d0babb5365